# Hardy maximal function on the torus

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

A few years ago [I asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281357/reference-for-the-hardy-maximal-function-on-the-torus) a reference about the Hardy maximal function on the flat torus. [Mateusz Kwaśnicki](https://mathoverflow.net/users/108637/mateusz-kwa%C5%9Bnicki) kindly answered in a comment, and confirmed my conviction that basically everything which is known on the whole space for the maximal function should also hold on $\mathbf{T}^d$. However, I am still searching for a reference or at least a simple argument for this " transference ".

More specifically, on the whole space, if $\rho$ is a non-negative function having an integrable radially decreasing majorant, we have the following estimate for any function $f$ locally integrable :  $|f\star \rho_n|\lesssim_{d,\rho} M f$, where $(\rho_n)_n$ stands for the approximate identiy issued from $\rho$.

How can we translate this result on the flat torus (for the corresponding convolution) ?